# Understanding mongoose findOne().remove()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

As you know, in `mongoose`, we can remove all users with age 30 like this:

```
User.find({age: 30}).remove(callback);
```

Now, replace `find()` with `findOne()`, and I think it should remove only 1 user:

```
User.findOne({age: 30}).remove(callback);
```

*oh, not as I expected, the code above also remove ALL instead of ONE*

**So, why `findOne().remove()` remove ALL instead of ONE? Is that a bug or a feature and why?**

Thanks in advance!

P/S: *I know `findOneAndRemove()` would remove one user for me, but in this question I want to understand findOne().remove()*

Comment: Feels like a bug to me (or at least unexpected behaviour). Perhaps worth considering filing a bug report about?

Comment: @robertklep You are right, I have reported this to mongoose team and got a reply.

Comment: @damphat did any of these answers deserve to be marked as correct?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have reported this question to mongoose team, and got a reply:

https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/1851#issuecomment-31355346

Here's the message from aheckmann

*"that's a good catch. findOne just sets the command name to run, remove() changes it back to a rice command but no limit was ever set. We should probably change that in 3.9 so that findOne sets
the limit as well."*

Answer (score 1):

Both `find` and `findOne` returns mongoose Query objects which only contains information about the model and the specified query. It's not taking into account `findOne` which is applied first in the callback. What you expect to happen is to have options be set like this `User.findOne({age: 30}, null, {limit: 1}).remove()` as this would only remove one and you could argue that this is a bug, but that depends on the usage. Like you have already pointed out, the right way to go is to use findOneAndRemove().

Comment: So why `mongoose` do not translate `findOne()` to `find({}, null, {litmit:1})`? Do you find any reason to not do the translation?

Comment: Not really, I guess it could be that there are some cases where it doesn't make sense to add limit and it depends on the underlying structure of the code, so that's why I won't say for certain that it's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I'm kind of a noob but wouldn't you need to put your remove in the callback because this is an asynchronous function? Try something like:

```
User.findOne({age: 30}, function(err, user){
    user.remove()
})
```

Comment: `findOne` return a `query object` instead of the result. So you do NOT have to put `remove` function inside the callback.